# How to get full keyboard on OSK

Tags: boot-camp, on-screen-keyboard

I'm on a partitioned Windows 10 and I would love to use PgDn and PgUp for my XNA game dev, but my Mac keyboard doesn't have those keys.  Because of that, I want the full OSK.  However, when I click the keyboard button, the full keyboard button is greyed out.  (I can't take a picture of it).  Can someone help?

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727766.aspx) is MSDN's documentation for it.

BTW, does this have anything to do with me not Activating?

Comment: To get any answers at all - we will need to know what OSK is and a bit more information as to why you need to do this.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas OSK = On-Screen Keyboard, `osk.exe`

Comment: @gronostaj Yup :)